# How does gitpitch work with private github repositories?

Tags: github, gitpitch

Posting this question on stackoverflow as requested by the `gitpitch` developer [here](https://github.com/gitpitch/gitpitch/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

When you commit a `PITCHME.md` file to a public GitHub repository, the presentation displays in this URL format: `https://gitpitch.com/user/repo`

However, where are presentations for private repositories displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been noted by the repo owner, that is not possible:

> private repos are not currently supported. Only PITCHME in public repos can be
>   rendered as slideshow presentations.

[Question relating to Private Repos #26](//github.com/gitpitch/gitpitch/issues/26)

Answer (score 2):

GitPitch Pro [was just released](https://medium.com/@gitpitch/announcing-gitpitch-pro-7a643cdd8e56) and includes support for private repos. The beta period just [ended on April 5, 2018](https://medium.com/@gitpitch/your-invitation-to-join-gitpitch-pro-beta-a613008c9c75). See the [gitpitch GitHub repo](https://github.com/gitpitch/gitpitch/) issue [here](https://github.com/gitpitch/gitpitch/issues/119#issuecomment-362474418).